# JSON/AJAX still displays error

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

#### Background

I have a web application which displays "simple" information about an account, i.e. Name and account Number....  I have a button on the side to display "detailed" information... i.e Name, Acct# and Phone#.

The system needs to pull the information dynamically upon clicking this button, and will populate into specified div's...  What am I doing wrong in this case, because I am **constantly receiving the alert with "Error Loading Information"**.  **Edit:** -Changed error alert to alert(textStatus) - Now all I have is "error" in the alert box....

#### JS/Ajax

```
$('.view_information').click(function(e) { 
            //On Clicking the function, dynamically load the data for the viewing
                var dataObj = {};
                dataObj["id"] = $(this).data('id'); 
                dataObj["action"] = "get"; // "get" or "set"
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'view_agency_info.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dataObj,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        /* Doesn't Work....*/
    $('.view_id').html(data.id);
    $('.view_name').html(data.name);
    $('.view_account').html(data.account);
    $('.view_phone').html(data.phone);
    /*Also Doesn't work...                      
    $('.view_id').html(data.message['id']);
    $('.view_name').html(data.message['name']);
    $('.view_account').html(data.message['account']);
    $('.view_phone').html(data.message['phone']);*/
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                       // alert('Error Loading Information');
                       alert(textStatus);
                    }
                    });
```

#### JSON

```
<?php
include_once('customer.class.php');
$customer = new Customer();
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1"; //expecting one row  

    try {
        $result = $customer->runQuery($query); //class function with fetchAll
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }       

$message = array( 
 'id' => $id,
 'name' => $result[0]['agency_name'], 
 'account' => $result[0]['account_number'], 
 'phone' => $result[0]['phone'] 
 );
 } 
  print json_encode($message); 
 ?>
```

Comment: don't output a fixed error message when you can have a dynamic one that includes information about WHY an error occured. e.g. how about `alert(textStatus)`? On a bigger picture level, if your JS code is expecting nothing BUT json text, then you server-side script should never output anything BUT json. if your query blows up, you output a plaintext error message, which will NOT be valid json. You'll never know why you get the error message, because all you say is "something's wrong".

Comment: @Marcb TBH There are many more functions being handed by the php script, so I dont believe it would be as simple as stated.... Since I am new to JSON and AJAX, if I switch up `alert(textStatus)` as mentioned, do I need to do anything else?... and on a side note, what isn't strictly json in particular?

Comment: `"Error: " ...` is just a plaintext string that will be output to the client. it'll be loaded into the JSON parser, causing it to barf. of course, that'd only occur if a db failure occured, but still... you'd be outputting non-json text into a json-required context.

Comment: @MarcB  ... by using alert(textStatus) I still only receive "error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was able to fix the syntax to get it operable....  Had to do with passing the array into json to execute.

I changed the JS/AJAX to:

```
/* Old Variable Definitions
//var dataObj = {};
//dataObj["id"] = $(this).data('id'); 
//dataObject["column"] = $(this).data('column');
//dataObj["action"] = "get"; // "get" or "set"*/

/* New Syntax: */
var data_id = $(this).data('id');
var data_action = "get";
var column_toact_on = $(this).data('column');
$.ajax({
    url: 'view_agency_info.php',
    type: 'POST',
    //data: dataObj, // OLD array
    data: {id : data_id, action: data_action, column: column_toact_on},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        alert("Wooptee Doo Basil!");}
```